# bootstrap pagination CSS make border around thicker but not the inside one

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

how can I make bootstrap pagination CSS  make border around thicker but not the inside one? like this image bellow?

[image]

I tried but the css I used make all, someone could help me on this?  thanks.

html:

```
<ul class="pagination pull-right">
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">116</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Last</a></li>
  </ul>
```

css:

```
.pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span {
   border: 4px solid #ddd;
}
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8hnhmxh8/

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/8hnhmxh8/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.pagination {
  border: 4px solid #ddd;
}
.pagination > li > a {
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   border-radius: 0px!important;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8hnhmxh8/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the border is on the a-tag, not the li-tag. But try this:

```
.pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span {
   border-top: 4px solid #ddd;
   border-bottom: 4px solid #ddd;
}

.pagination>li:first-of-type > a {
  border-left: 4px solid #ddd;
}

.pagination>li:last-of-type > a {
  border-right: 4px solid #ddd;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8hnhmxh8/1/

Answer (score -1):

Instead of applying the border on `li` element do it only on `ul` element.

```
.pagination {
   border: 4px solid #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can update border to .

`.ul {
border:1px solid black;
padding:10px;
}`

I have forked your code.

https://jsfiddle.net/4p7413jz/1/

Hope it works!!!